# Segmentation fault in running docker image on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, dockerfile, dockerhub

I have created a simple angular application with docker. It is running successfully in my local machine. But when I run the Image after taking pull from docker hub on AWS EC2 Instance (t2.micro) I am getting `segmentation fault` error. Even after runnig I am not able to do `docker ps`

This is my `DOCKERFILE`

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json /app/

RUN npm install

COPY . /app/

EXPOSE 4200

# Serve the app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I researched on this thing but the only thing I get is node version issue. So, I changed it to the latest version (tried 10, 11) but still I am facing same error.

I don't know what to do now. Please help

Comment: Do you have a `.dockerignore` file that keeps your build system's `node_modules` from overwriting the `npm install` content?

Comment: Yes, ```.dockerignore``` is there @DavidMaze